# Email Verifier PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, ports

My goal is to make an emailVerifier.php which send an email to see if the actual email adress exist or not.

That's what I've done from this library : https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail
And it's works really well in local, but when I try on my website online, the server doesn't responding yet so it can't verify the adress.

I've tried 3 different SMTP ports 25, 587, 465, but nothing changes. Any ideas of where the problem should be ?

Thannk you.

Comment: Why not just send a verify link in the email?

Comment: Because a lot of potential users will run away from my register form, haha.

Comment: Sounds like your "users" might be robots. Email verification is standard practice today.

Comment: They might be robots, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, this is way harder than this because of how ESPs react to bad email addresses.

You can't necessarily validate an email address without being signed up for one of the various feedback loops.

What you can do is validate that an email conforms the RFC using php, or check that MX records exist from the DNS.  But you can't figure out if the email address conforms to the house styles of various email services.

A more robust way to do this is this project:

https://github.com/mailgun/flanker

If you just want to do the MX records use this:

https://packagist.org/packages/service-to/validate-email